# Is trigger comes as part of transaction in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

I have three tables in SQL Server:

1. Employee
2. EmployeeDetails
3. EmployeeHistory

I wrote a trigger on the `Employee` table so that if entry is inserted into `Employee`, then it also inserts a row into `EmployeeHistory`; which is working fine.

Now I have created stored procedure with transaction and inserting records into `Employee`, then `EmployeeDetails`. After inserting the record into `Employee` and if there is any issue and the transaction is rolled back, then will the row inserted into `EmployeeHistory` also be removed or not?

Comment: Why don't you try and see for yourself?

Comment: Execution of a trigger always takes place within a transaction that includes the original statement, so if the trigger fails, the original statement is rolled back. Rather than asking, though, you can simply test it: use `RAISERROR` or `SELECT 1 / 0` to simulate failure. Due to T-SQL's [arcane rules for error handling](http://sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html), testing to see what actually happens is always a good idea anyway.

Comment: Agreed let me try myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**By default, the option `XACT_ABORT` is `ON` in a trigger.** [It can be seen here](https://lextonr.wordpress.com/tag/xact_abort/). When this feature is `ON`, any error that occurs break off/abort the batch, so your whole transaction will be rolled back.

[Microsoft documentation says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> When SET XACT_ABORT is ON, if a Transact-SQL statement raises a
>   run-time error, the entire transaction is terminated and rolled back.
>
> When SET XACT_ABORT is OFF, in some cases only the Transact-SQL
>   statement that raised the error is rolled back and the transaction
>   continues processing. Depending upon the severity of the error, the
>   entire transaction may be rolled back even when SET XACT_ABORT is OFF.

Comment: I do not understand the terminology XACT_ABORT here but i tried and it is working like trigger value is also coming in transaction if roll back then all part is going to roll back.

Comment: @chandraprakashkabra please, read my updated answer again to see what `xact_abort` for.

Comment: Yup now understood. But in your first post you are saying that By default XACT_ABORT is ON and in second it is OFF.? Little confusion here.

Comment: @chandraprakashkabra for trigger XACT_ABORT is ON, but for other situations XACT_ABORT is OFF. Please, read this article https://lextonr.wordpress.com/tag/xact_abort/