# Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 28 The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

I'm getting error while calling one statement through trigger I want to run trigger fine even if it has error inside it. so I used try and catch for that.

but even applying rollback and try/catch getting this error

> Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 28 The transaction ended in the
> trigger. The batch has been aborted.

```
create table dbo.trigger_log(
id int,
message varchar(50),
lodadatetime datetime2 
)

create table dbo.trigger_test (
id int,
name varchar(50),
status varchar(50)
)

create or alter TRIGGER [dbo].[trigger_error]
ON dbo.trigger_test
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
set xact_abort off
    begin try
     -- some insert/update operation 
     insert into dbo2.trigger_log(id, message, loaddatetime)
     select 1, 'sdfsd',getdate()
     insert into dbo2.trigger_log(id, message, loaddatetime)
     select 1, 'sdfsd','df'
    end try
    begin catch
    rollback
      select 1
    end catch
end

insert into dbo.trigger_test 
select 1,'xyz','ok'

select * from dbo2.trigger_log
select * from dbo.trigger_test
```

Any Solution for this?

Is there a way that my trigger run successfully and throw error.
I just want in case of failure inside trigger. Insertion/Update we are performing on main table shouldn't be affected.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53349469/is-trigger-comes-as-part-of-transaction-in-sql-server  (especially Execution of a trigger always takes place within a transaction that includes the original statement, so if the trigger fails, the original statement is rolled back.)

Comment: I'm using SQL server

Comment: 1. I'm *really* not a fan of doing a `ROLLBACK` in a trigger; it gives an ambiguous error to the user and doesn't tell them the problem. Use a `THROW` instead to pass a *meaningful* error the to front end and have the outer transaction handle the rollback. 2. Returning a dataset from a `TRIGGER` is deprecated and *should not* be done.

Comment: Hi thom a, can you please write demo query for this

Comment: A demo query for *what* exactly? The `ROLLBACK` isn't even needed in this case, if I am honest. You can just attempt to `INSERT` a row into your table `dbo.trigger_log` and if it fails the whole transaction will "automagically" fail. The content of your trigger only needs to be the `INSERT` and nothing else.

Comment: You seem to have bitten by the myth that nested transactions are real.

Answer (score 0):

If you rollback in a trigger then everything is rolled back, and you should never do this. If you actually wanted a rollback then you can simply remove the `SET XACT_ABORT OFF` as well as the `TRY CATCH` and it will get rolled back.

In this case, you want to swallow the error, so you need to remove the `ROLLBACK`.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trigger_error]
ON dbo.trigger_test
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS

SET XACT_ABORT OFF;
SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO dbo.trigger_log (id, message, loaddatetime)
    SELECT 1, 'sdfsd','df';
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH;
```

Do not `select` data out of a trigger, it's not properly supported.

`TRY` with an empty `CATCH` is an odd thing to do anyway. You should probably consider *why* you are getting errors and try to avoid them.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion the trigger you have is overly complicated and flawed.

Firstly I suggest against using `ROLLBACK` in the `TRIGGER`. For the above there is no need for it, as when the `INSERT` statement fails the error generated will be propagated to the outer scope, and *that* will present the error to the front end. As the trigger failed, then the transaction will also be "automagically" rolled back.

*If* you need to add logic in your trigger so that in the event of *some logic* you want the DML statement to fail then `THROW` a **meaningful** error, don't `ROLLBACK`; this gives the front end a meaningful error and the transaction is still rolled back.

You also have a `SELECT 1` in your trigger which isn't part of a assignment/DML operation. Returning a dataset from a trigger is deprecated and should be avoided. I don't know what the goal of the `SELECT` in the above is, it just `SELECT`s the `int` value `1`, so I assume it should simply not be there.

This end up with your DDL statements just being the following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.trigger_log(id int,
                             message varchar(50),
                             loaddatetime datetime2(7)); --Corrected spelling

CREATE TABLE dbo.trigger_test (id int,
                               name varchar(50),
                               status varchar(50));
GO

CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trigger_error] ON dbo.trigger_test
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO dbo.trigger_log(id, message, loaddatetime)
    VALUES( 1, 'sdfsd','df');
END;
GO
```

If you then try to `INSERT` into the table `dbo.trigger_test` like you did, the following error now occurs:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.trigger_test (id, name, status)
VALUES (1,'xyz','ok');
```

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trigger_error, Line 6
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

In truth, "swallowing" an error is just *not* a good idea in any scenario. If the trigger errors, then there's a problem and it should be addressed. In this case, that's because of the incorrect data attempted to be inserted into the table `dbo.trigger_log`. That should be addressed. For a log table, inserting data into the "main" table and *not* doing the appropriate logging could be a significant concern so you *need* to be aware.

Comment: Hi as per requirement i have to do some insert update delete operation in trigger, that's why I'm doing rollback

Comment: Again, don't, @Keshav . If you need to cause an error the `THROW` one.